# book for (investment banking) market risk overview

Tags: books, market-risk

what is a good intro book / course / source of knowledge on the topic of Market Risk for investment banking? I'm IT person cooperating with quants market risk team, and found myself either missing some finance knowledge and or getting confused on a generic terms meaning within market risk context. Tried a few books, but the likes of "Options, futures and other derivatives" etc are way too detailed to me, I need to have a broad overall understanding, rather than see through the math on a specific models. (Detailed book will be still fine if organized in a way the basic concepts can be picked up separately without forcing me to dive too deep into each subject)

(note there was user in a somehow similar situation posting [Book recommendation for credit risk management for banking](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17588/book-recommendation-for-credit-risk-management-for-banking) but - besides aiming for a different risk field - it was asked many years ago)

Comment: I think the linked question is aimed at people that are already quants, not people wanting to gain Quant knowledge.

Comment: Can you mention some concepts that you found confusing or areas where you found you did not understand the terminology

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Carol Alexander](https://www.coalexander.com/), [*Market Risk Analysis*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470997990) (2008), volumes [I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470998008), [II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470998016),  [III](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470997893),  [IV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470997885).

[Workbooks](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/carol-alexander-426914b8_marketriskanalysis-riskmanagement-riskanalysis-activity-6977180965198516224-GOYL)

**Edit:** while she's an excellent general reference as of 2008, she doesn't cover topics that arose in the last 15 years, for example, risk not in VaR (RNIV) or FRTB. I suspect that IT development might be disproportionately focused on the later. You may need more focused questions on specific topics.